# POSTGRESQL trigger troubles

Tags: postgresql

Wrote this code. Problem with this code is that it's doing nothing. Should update `OTB_Name` when I'm updating table, but nothing happens.

Can somebody tell me where my problem is?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.demand_lom_ar5_tracker() 
RETURNS trigger AS $demand_lom_ar5_tracker$
BEGIN
    -- INSERT
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        UPDATE public.demand_lom_ar5
            SET "OTB_Name" = ar5_area_otb."OTB_Name"
            FROM mapinfo.public.ar5_area_otb
            WHERE ST_Contains (mapinfo.public.demand_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY", mapinfo.public.ar5_area_otb."SP_GEOMETRY");
        RETURN NULL;
    -- UPDATE
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        UPDATE public.demand_lom_ar5
            SET "OTB_Name" = ar5_area_otb."OTB_Name"
            FROM mapinfo.public.ar5_area_otb
            WHERE NEW."MI_PRINX" = OLD."MI_PRINX" and ST_Contains (mapinfo.public.demand_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY", mapinfo.public.ar5_area_otb."SP_GEOMETRY");
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;

$demand_lom_ar5_tracker$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

--apply the trigger:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_demand_lom_ar5_tracker 
  ON public.demand_lom_ar5;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_demand_lom_ar5_tracker 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.demand_lom_ar5
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.demand_lom_ar5_tracker();
```

Comment: You need a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies `NEW`. But why do you want to persist the information? Calculate it when you `SELECT`, perhaps using a view.

Comment: Tried with BEFORE - deleting object. 
Changed to RETURN NEW; after the function - nothing, but DB is thinking few minutes after save. (In this layer I have about 10 000 objects)

Can you explain in few words what do you mean about SELECT ?

Comment: I do not understand your first sentence at all. More about `SELECT`: create a view like `SELECT d.*, a."OTB_Name" FROM demand_lom_ar5 AS d JOIN ar5_area_otb AS a ON ST_Contains(d."SP_GEOMETRY", a."SP_GEOMETRY")`

Comment: I have no clue how to use SELECT in my case. Maybe you can explain?

-I need to update layer "demand"  from layer "area_otb" .
When I'm saving new demand I want fill inside value from column 'OTB_NAME'. Each "demand" polygon is inside of some "area_otb", so why I decided to do it by contains. 

My problem that when I'm saving DB thinking a lot and then nothing. Column is not updated.

Comment: I am suggesting that you don't store that redundant information in the table. If `ar5_area_otb` is modified, the information will become wrong! Instead, calculate the information on the fly when you select from the table.

Comment: Now I see..

But it's will be complicated. I'm using postgresql like "cloud" for GIS. I'm already connected to this DB mapinfo, qgis, android tablets, web portal. One thing is to modify query  for MapInfo or Qgis, hut If need modify api for web and for tablets  it's became to much complicated.  

So why I choose this way - to update columns directly in DB. 
History is working, but now I'm stuck with this issue.. 

If you have an idea how to help me, you will save my head =)

Comment: I'll try. `BEFORE`triggers would be the right thing, but you said that that didn't work for you either. Could you edit your question and add the `BEFORE` trigger and function?